# Unknown C++ statement

Tags: c++, opencv

Currently, I'm developing a C++ project using OpenCV, which is a library used for image processing.

Looking at some examples, I came across the following line:

```
Mat gray, smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );
```

I'd never seen something like this in C/C++ before...do you have any idea what this is doing?

Comment: That code makes sense. It's a declaration of `gray` and `smallImg`, with the former using the default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a declaration of several variables in one line.

Without obfuscation, it is equivalent to this:

```
Mat gray;
Mat smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );
```

which shouldn't need any further explanation.

(In Ancient Times, when storage was sparse and terminals showed 24 lines of code, if you were lucky, using multiple-variable declarations made more sense than it does now.)

Answer (score 4):

`Mat` is a class, `gray` is declared and defined with a no arg constructor (makes sense since gray would be the default color, no?), `smallImg` is declared and defined with a three arg constructor.